# Switching from facebox to SASS bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I want to switch from facebox to the SASS version of [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal) modal for my new projects.

With facebox I just had to add `:rel => "facebox"` in my `link_to(...)` :

```
      <%= link_to "My Action",
             { :controller => :my_controller,
               :action => :my_action },
             { :rel => "facebox", :class=>"button"} %>
```

this would load the HTML from `:my_action` view into the modal box! Easy!

Now how do I do that using bootstrap-sass modal?

Answer (score 1):

Just a question: are you trying to show an external (either a iframe or AJAX loaded page) in that modal?

In this case I'm afraid that the Bootstrap Modal **doesn't** support this. As i can see in the docs and in the [source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js), you'll only be able to show another element (referenced by its id) in the page.

Answer (score 1):

I created a shim to allow drop-in replacement for the old "facebox" so it'll work perfectly with Bootstrap modals:

https://github.com/mdchaney/facebox-bootstrap